# The Seifert-Van Kampen theorem as a push-out

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, groupoids

My question concerns the proof of the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem. The version of such a statement that interests me is the following.

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $U, V\subseteq X$ two path-connected open subsets such that $U\cap V\subseteq X$ is path connected. Consider the push-out of the commutative diagram

$
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad\pi_{1}(U)\longleftarrow \pi_{1}(U\cap V) \longrightarrow \pi_{1}(V)
$

in the category of groupoids. Then this colimit is isomorphic to $\pi_{1}(X)$.

I would like to find a simple proof of this statement, possibly one that is constructed by verifying directly the universal property on $\pi_{1}(X)$. Links to (free) further readings are also welcome - I found a paper that gives such description a long time ago, but I cannot find it anymore. In what way is the hypothesis that the open subsets $U$, $V$ and $U\cap V$ are path-connected useful? Is there a version of this statement that uses weaker hypothesis on the covering?

Comment: Simplicity is in the eye of the beholder, but this is the viewpoint adopted in Massey's "Algebraic Topology".

Comment: Concerning your last question : yes there is. Denotes $\Pi$ the fundamental groupoid functor, then $\Pi$ maps $U \cup V$ to the pushout of $\Pi(U) \leftarrow \Pi(U\cap V) \rightarrow \Pi(V)$ in $\mathsf{Grpds}$ without restriction on the open sets $U,V$ or $U \cap V$.

Comment: Do you know the proof of the usual SVK theorem?

Comment: One can ommit the path-connectedness of $U,V$, and $U\cap V$. If $A$ is any subset of $X$ which meets every path-component of $U,V$ and $U\cap V$, then the pushout of $\pi(U,A)\leftarrow\pi(U\cap V,A)\to\pi(V,A)$ in the category of groupoids is $\pi(X,A)$, where $\pi(Y,A)$ is the fundamental groupoid of $Y$ whose objects are restricted to the elements of $A\cap Y$. A proof for this can be found in Brown's *Topology and Groupoids*.

Comment: Since you ask for free further reading I mention this paper: http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/brown-razak.pdf which gives the statement for a general cover and a set of base points, and the proof by verification of the universal property. This is the proof that generalises to higher dimensions. For a discussion, see http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/galway7.pdf

Comment: Why not posting all these answers as answers, not just as comments?